# Can't start vitualenv outside of python project

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

I was working with my project and virtualenv together and read someplace that this isn't the best practice along with it mucked up my git repo.

Now I have cleaned my project folder (pyHoliday) and updated the gitignore file. Purged the system and started fresh doing:

1. create a folder to hold the env and project files (pyHoliday/): `mkdir Documents/dev/pyHoliday`
2. cd to pyHoliday/: `cd pyholiday`
3. clone the pyHoliday python files into pyHoliday/: `git clone https://github.com/LanceGundersen/pyHoliday.git`
4. create python3 vituralenv: `virtualenv -p python3 env`
5. enable env virtualenv: `source env/bin/activate`
6. cd to python project: `cd pyHoliday`
7. install requirements: `pip install -r requirements.txt`
8. install project: `python setup.py install` -> Get a warning

   `running install_lib
   warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install`
9. Try to run the project: `holiday`

   `Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/lance/Documents/dev/pyHoliday/env/bin/holiday", line 6, in <module>
   from pyHoliday.pyHoliday import run
   ImportError: No module named 'pyHoliday'`

   Any clue what is going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not directly an answer but maybe this makes your life easier. So you should take a look at virtualenvwrapper (https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which has the purpose of make it more easy to use virtualenvs in general. It keeps all your venvs in one place and you can point to you project folder so that you in the right directoy automatically when activativating your venv.

Comment: I took your advice on the virtualenvwrapper! This makes it simpler to understand (for me anyways). Now though I am getting a version issue but I don't think its exactly related to this but rather its a gitHub release versioning thing. Thoughts? says: Assert tag is not None, 'cant parse version %s' % tag
AssertionError: cant parse version None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you [repository](https://github.com/LanceGundersen/pyHoliday) `pyHoliday` is not a package but a `pyHoliday.py` module, so you shouldn't declare it as a package but as an item in `py_modules` (in `setup.cfg`):

```
py_modules =
    pyHoliday
```

On the other hand you need to declare `programs` as a package.

List `site-packages/` in your virtual environment to see what is and what isn't installed.